# How to edit my .htaccess so that Silex gets the right route?

Tags: php, .htaccess, silex

I've had some problems after uploading Silex to my webserver since it grabbed the wrong Route:

> No route found for "GET /Escape/public/"

It should have grabbed `"GET /"`, so I therefore think it can be fixed by a .htaccess which is currently looking like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /path/to/app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Escape/public/ index.php [QSA,L]
```

My URL is looking like this:
www.MyWebsite.nl/Escape/public/#route

I hoped this .htacces would already do the job for me, but... it does not :(
How do I have to rewrite so that Silex picks up the right Routecall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```